# Docker Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - use tcpdump to capture GRE packets

Tags: ubuntu, docker, tcpdump

I've created a docker image that's derived from the `ubuntu:16.04` [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) and started a container based on this image. Within this container, I tried capturing GRE packets using `tcpdump`. However, when I run `tcpdump -i <interface> proto gre` within the container, I get the following error:

```
tcpdump: unknown ip proto 'gre'
```

Any idea how this could be fixed?

**NOTE**: The container uses the host networking stack (ie, The container is started with `--net="host"`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

According to the [pcap-filter](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) man page, you can only specify the following *protos*: **ether**, **fddi**, **tr**, **wlan**, **ip**, **ip6**, arp, **rarp**, **decnet**, **tcp** and **udp**.

However, you can use the *slicing* operator like this instead: `"ip[9:1]=47"`

If you refer to [RFC791 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1), you will see that the *Protocol* field of the IP header is the 10th byte of the header, or a 1 byte field located at offset 9, which is what `ip[9:1]` isolates.  Further, as specified in [RFC2784, Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2784) (as well as being registered as protocol number 47 with  [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml)), GRE is protocol 47.

**NOTES**:

- While the pcap-filter and `tcpdump` man pages don't use the term *slicing* to describe the `[]` operator, Wireshark does use this terminology in the [wireshark-filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) man page, hence I use it here as well.
- `tcpdump` examples use the single equal sign `=` in their examples while Wireshark uses double equal signs `==` in their examples.  In practice, both of them work, so feel free to use either one.
- Since you're only interested in a single byte, you don't actually need to specify the length value within the *slice* operator, `"ip[9]==47"` will work just as well too.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for looking into this. A couple of points: (i) I'm able to run tcpdump with `proto gre` filter on the host machine (on which the docker container runs) (ii) replacing that with `proto 47` works fine within the docker

Comment: I tried "ip proto 47", but it failed in my testing.  I might be running an older version of tcpdump/libpcap (can't check at the moment); what version of tcpdump/libpcap are you running, both on the host machine and within docker?

Comment: Also, if "ip proto gre" works, then it would seem that the pcap-filter documentation needs updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tcpdump -i any proto 47
```